# Dialogflow CX: Is there a way to assign the fulfillment message to a session parameter?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Is there a way to copy the fulfillment message to a session parameter in Dialogflow CX? The idea is to have that message available during subsequent routing when matching a "repeat" intent.

Assigning the fulfillment to a parameter and subsequently using it does not work because I need to support multiple languages, and parameters are not language specific.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, there is no easy way to assign a language-specific value to a parameter other than resorting to a webhook or something similar.